# Split cell value on comma and match ins elements to a list

Tags: excel, split, match, vba

I am trying to split cell values on a comma when they exit in col A of sheet Orgs

And then I want to match the elements of the split cell to a list of values in column A on sheet Orgs_Helper

But my Sud always says there is a match even though that cant be true

Thanks

Orgs Sheet Looks Like:

```
ColA
Maryland Community Health Resources Commission
Baltimore City Schools


CDPH
DPSS, DMH
Alex
DHS, DPH, DPSS, LASD
Los Angeles Sherrif Dept, Whole Person Care, Housing for Health, Office of 
Immigrant Affairs
LAC+USC Medical Center

Middlesex Sheriff's Office

Behavioral Health Systems Baltimore
NIH
```

Orgs_Helper looks like

```
ColAor
AACP
Alex
Baltimore City Schools
Behavioral Health Systems Baltimore
Boys and Girls Club
Department of Health
Department of Labor
Department of Social Services
HOPWA
Housing Authority
Housing for Health
HUD
Justice System
LAC+USC Medical Center
LASD
Los Angeles Sherrif Dept
```

What I have so far
    Sub FindReplace_DilimCellValues()
    Dim G As Variant
    Dim wsFV As Worksheet, wsRV As Worksheet
    Dim sLR As Long, tLR As Long, i As Long, n As Long

```
Set wsFV = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orgs")
Set wsRV = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Orgs_Helper")

sLR = wsFV.Range("A" & wsFV.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
tLR = wsRV.Range("A" & wsRV.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To sLR

      G = Split(wsFV.Cells(i, 1).value, ", ")
      For n = LBound(G) To UBound(G)
            If Not IsError(Application.Match(splitCell(wsFV.Cells(i, 1).value, ", ", n), wsRV.Range("A2:A" & tLR), 0)) Then
              MsgBox "Match found"

          End If
       Next n

    Next i
End Sub
```

Helper Function:

```
Function splitCell(strValue As String, delim As String, n As Long) As String

  If strValue <> "" Then
   splitCell = Split(strValue, delim)(n)
 Else
   strValue = ""
 End If
```

End Function

Comment: "my Sud"? It doesn't find e.g. CDPH. What is it finding that you think it shouldn't. It's pretty hard to tell just using a message box to see what is found though.

Comment: Btw your function seems redundant.